# math and operator behavior

Tags: php

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$oldprice = $_SESSION['price'][$id-=1];
```

This works but unfortunately now `$id` whenever referenced is one less than it should be where I need it.

I've tried `$modified_id = $id-=1;` to try and keep the original `$id` variable and create a new 'modified' variable with the value of `$id` minus 1 but it all seems to have the same effect of modifying the original. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: what made you think `-=` was the correct operator to use here rather than just `-`?

Comment: $oldprice = $_SESSION['price'][$id--];

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to change the value of `$id`, use

```
$oldprice = $_SESSION['price'][$id-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not keeping the original $id in `$modified_id = $id-=1;`; $id will be 1 less.

Try

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$oldprice = $_SESSION['price'][$id-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this now

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$saved_id = $id - 1;
$oldprice = $_SESSION['price'][$saved_id];
```